# Exclude *.spec.js files in Rails asset pipeline (application.js)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, sprockets

I'm attempting to follow John Papa's AngularJs 1.x styleguide ([organising tests](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y197)) and place `*.spec.js` files (to be executed using Karma) next to client code, which results in files such as `some.filter.js` and `some.filter.spec.js` being place next to one another.

However, what I need to avoid, is including the `*.spec.js` files in the assets pipeline.

The only options I see for now are either avoiding using `//= require_tree .` in the `application.js` file and specifying every single file explicitly, or giving up on keeping spec files next to the code.

Is there any better way of achieving the desired behaviour?

(I'm using sprockets 3.5.2 and rails 4.2.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note: this answer is based on the [defsprite's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36108290/688865), because it pointed me in the right direction, but reality turned out to be a bit harsher.

Place the following in `config/initializers/sprockets.rb` to register a new sprockets processor:

```
class DirectiveProcessor < Sprockets::DirectiveProcessor
  def process_require_glob_directive(glob)
    each_file(glob) { |fn| process_require_directive(fn) }
  end

  def process_stub_glob_directive(glob)
    each_file(glob) { |fn| process_stub_directive(fn) }
  end

  private

  def each_file(glob)
    glob_pattern = "#{@dirname}/#{glob}"
    path_prefix = Pathname.new(@dirname)

    Dir[glob_pattern].sort.each do |path|
      yield Pathname.new(path).relative_path_from(path_prefix).to_s
    end
  end
end

Rails.application.config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.register_processor('application/javascript', DirectiveProcessor)
end
```

The most notable changes with respect to the original answer include converting absolute paths returned by `Dir` to relative ones (absolute paths are not accepted by sprockets) and different registration method (`Rails.application.assets` is `nil` in my case).

Then, within your `application.js` (before any `require_tree` statements) add:

```
//= stub_glob angular/**/*.spec.js
```

Answer (score 4):

Sprockets itself does not implement file globbing (yet) - this can only achieved by providing a custom `DirectiveProcessor`. Luckily, there is already a gem providing exactly what you want: https://github.com/backupify/sprockets-glob

From the documentation:

```
# config/initializers/sprockets.rb
require 'sprockets/glob'
Rails.application.assets.register_processor('application/javascript', Sprockets::Glob::DirectiveProcessor)

# application.js
//= require_glob features/**/*.js
//= stub_glob features/**/*test.js
```